# speech waiting for localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a TTS application in ASP.NET. All I want for now is for the application to speak the text when I press the button.

Webform1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="speechtest.WebForm1" Async="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSpeechProgress" runat="server" Text="Progress"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSpeak" runat="server" OnClick="btnSpeak_Click" Text="Speak" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace speechtest
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnSpeak_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            PromptBuilder pb = new PromptBuilder();
            pb.AppendText("Hello world!");
            synthesizer.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            synthesizer.Speak(pb);
        }
    }
}
```

The text is being spoken when I press the button, like I expected, but the problem is that the page doesn't stop loading and shows "waiting for localhost".

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Before you continue on this path, you do realise that this will make the _server_ speak and not the client?

Comment: No I did not...

Comment: So how do I make the client speak?

Comment: The only way is to play an audio file (which is really annoying when a website does this without asking).